# Best approach to implement safe $apply in Angular Service/Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

I'm using the `socket.io`client in my Angular WebApp. I wrapped it up in a service, but that might not necessarily be of interest. However, since the incoming data is in a different scope than the controller which is using the service, I always have to call `$scope.$apply`. Even worse I found a few situations (during connect/reconnect) where I would have to use a `safeApply` as explained [here](https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma).

I understand that this is an [Angular Anti-Pattern](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns), however I don't see a way around this.

Is there a general way to solve this (preferably inside the service) that does not pollute the controllers with a lot of `$scope.$apply/safeApply`?

BR,
Daniel

Here is also some code, working, but not nice:

```
angular.module('mean')
    .controller('ConnectionStateController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.safeApply = function (fn) {
            var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
            if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
                if (fn && (typeof (fn) === 'function')) {
                    fn();
                }
            } else {
                this.$apply(fn);
            }
        };

        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
        $scope.message = 'Not connected';
        socket.on('connect', function () {
            $scope.safeApply(function () {
                $scope.message = "Connected";
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you know that `socket.io` operations are *always* going to be run asynchronously and that makes it a [valid place to use `$scope.$apply` (towards the bottom of the page)](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-%24scope.%24apply%28%29).

I would recommend **not using `safeApply` and explicitly calling `$scope.$apply`**. Using `safeApply` is going to cover up for genuine mistakes in implementation. Also, if you are wrapping your code in a service, you can inject the `$rootScope` in the service and call the async functions in `$rootScope.$apply`. Then you would not need to call `$scope.$apply` in each controller.

Comment: Oh man. I'm still a noob. I wouldn't actually know how to use `$scope.$apply`in a service after all. Also putting it into the `$rootScope`doesn't seem to be a nice alternative as well (I know you guys do this often), because that could be overridden by properties of an inner scope, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer the question myself, since I have a working solution using `defer`s. Nevertheless I'm not sure if I did it right. Here's the service:

```
angular.module('mean')
    .factory('ConnectionService', function ($q, $timeout) {
        var bindings = {};
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');
        // catch all events by overriding the socket's $emit
        var $emit = socket.$emit;
        socket.$emit = function (event, obj) {
            console.log('***', 'on', '"' + event + '"', obj);
            if (bindings.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
                bindings[event].notify(obj);
            }
            $emit.apply(socket, arguments);
        };

        return {
            socket: socket,
            observe: function (event, callback) {
                if (!bindings.hasOwnProperty(event)) {
                    bindings[event] = $q.defer();
                }
                bindings[event].promise.then(null, null, function (data) { 
                    callback.apply(this, [ data ]);
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

This allows a controller to use the service like this:

```
ConnectionService.observe('news', function (data) {
    $scope.message = data;
});
```

Not sure, if that's a nice solution or if it has side effects, that I don't see yet.

BR,
Daniel